# Find the singular points of $f$ and determine which are removable

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

Consider the function $$f(z)=\frac{\tan(z)}{z}, \quad z \in \mathbb{C}$$

I want to find it's singular points, determine which are removable and classify the smallest positive non-removable singular point.

I know that $f$ has a singular point at $z=0$, which is removable since $\lim_{z \to 0}f(z) \neq0$. How do I find any others and then classify the smallest non removable one though?

Comment: It should be obvious that the only other singular points of f are singular points of $tan(x)= \frac{sin(x)}{cos(x)}$.  What can you say about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

Note that $\tan(z)=\frac{\sin(z)}{\cos(z)}$ and $\cos(z)=0$ for $z=(n+1/2)\pi$ where $n$ is any integer.

Then, note that $\lim_{z\to (n-1/2)\pi}\frac{z-(n-1/2)\pi}{\cos(z)}=(-1)^n$

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. How do I use the limit you gave in order to show that $\lim_{z \to (n+1/2)\pi} (z-(n+1/2)\pi) \tan(z)/z \neq 0$?

Comment: What is the limit of the sine function?

Comment: As $z \to (n+1/2)\pi$ it's $(-1)^n$?

Comment: Well done!  You have it now.  Pleased to see that the hint was useful.  -Mark

Comment: So the smallest positive non-removable singularity is $z=\pi /2$?

Comment: What do you mean by smallest?  There are poles at $\pm \pi/2$.